# Why is Skype is not sending live video?

Tags: lubuntu, skype

I am using Lubuntu. When using Skype I can't send video, but I can receive video. What do I have to do to get this working? Does it need any additional driver software?

Comment: your camera have linux support, Is it working out skype?

Comment: yes camera have linux support..

Comment: helo please help